# Pandas - Decimal format when writing to_csv instead of scientific

Tags: python, pandas

I've just started using Pandas and I'm trying to export my dataset using the `to_csv` function on my dataframe `fp_df`

One column (entitled `fp_df['Amount Due']`)has multiple decimal places (the result is 0.000042) - but when using to_csv it's being output in a scientific notation, which the resulting system will be unable to read. It needs to be output as '0.000042'.

What is the easiest way to do this? The other answers I've found seem overly complex and I don't understand how or why they work.

(Apologies if any of my terminology is off, I'm still learning)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [the documentation for `to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), you'll find an attribute called `float_format`

```
df.to_csv(..., float_format='%.6f')
```

you can define the format you want as defined in the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: Thanks! I guess the data is being output in scientific notation because it's stored as a "float"? Can I ask what `%.6f` means? Does it mean "round to six decimal places"? EDIT: Thank you! Answered perfectly

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The `float_format` will only be applied to columns that are of type `float`

Comment: Sorry - I think my issue stemmed from the fact that I hadn't quite grasped what a "float" was. Your answer has helped me learn - thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel your question has been answered, consider accepting the answer with the check mark on the left to mark the question closed.